# Not able to send values to the input text field in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

HTML code

```
<textarea type="text" name="pos_description" rows="4" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-minlength ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" id="pos_description" placeholder="Enter Description" ng-model="data.description" minlength="150" maxlength="5000" required="">
                  </textarea>
```

My code

```
element(by.model('data.description')).sendKeys("Values");
```

Using this code am able to send values to text field in Firefox not in Chrome.

Comment: What happens in chrome? Do you see any errors? What if you click the area before sending keys? What protractor version are u using? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I am getting this error  : StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: @alecxe Protractor version :  v0.10.22.

Comment: Why haven't you upgraded yet - 0.10.22 is very very old.

Comment: @raghavendrat run the command `npm update protractor` if you installed protractor locally. If its installed globally then run `npm update -g protractor`.

Comment: @GirishSortur  Y am not able to send values to Input text field in chrome

Comment: @raghavendrat did you try updating your protractor, chromedriver, chrome browser and selenium-webdriver and see if it helps you to send the value to text area. If everything is up-to-date then your command should work

Comment: @GirishSortur I updated protractor to Version 1.0.0-rc2.

Comment: @raghavendrat the latest version of protractor is 2.5.1. Here's the link to it -  [protractor version](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). Please update to the latest version available

Comment: @GirishSortur ok but in google it is showing 1.0.0-rc2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93576/discussion-between-girish-sortur-and-raghavendra-t).